# Не работает OrderBy().ThenBy()

Tags: c#, linq

Есть массив строк, которые содержат одинаковые значения, мне необходимо его сгруппировать и вывести значения и количество повторений. Для этого использую `LINQ`

```
List<string> toGroupList = new List<string>();
//заполняю...
//пытаюсь сортировать
var gropedList = toGroupList.GroupBy(n => n).
    Select(group => new { Word = group.Key, Count = group.Count() }).
    OrderBy(s => s.Word).ThenBy(s => s.Count);
```

При этом отдельно `OrderBy()` работает, а в совокупности с `ThenBy()` - нет.

Comment: добавь пример данных на которых пробуешь, а так же текущий результат и ожидаемый результат

Comment: судя по коду, смысла в _ThenBy_ - нет, так как _s.Word_ уникальные

Comment: @Grundy запостили бы ответом.

Comment: @andreycha, непонятно, что хочет получить автор, а в таком виде это не ответ же как таковой. Думаю стоит подождать правки автора(если она вообще будет).

Comment: Спасибо, понял свою ошибку

Comment: @AlexKrass если автор спрашивает "Почему у меня не получается забить гвозди?", то ответ "Потому что вы пытаетесь забить их в бетон" с объяснением, почему так нельзя делать и как надо делать -- вполне является хорошим ответом. Естественно я не предлагаю ограничиваться одним предложением.

Comment: @andreycha, ну не :-) мне кажется тут больше - не воспроизводится, опечатка, тем более автор сам похоже разобрался

Comment: @andreycha, написал, но что-то мне кажется не совсем в ту сторону ушел :-)

Comment: @Grundy отлично написали!

Comment: @Grundy, Ваш ответ, несомненно, хороший, но является ли он ответом на поставленный вопрос? Мы уже натыкались на подобную проблему. Данному вопросу необходимо редактирование, так как на него не дать конкретного ответа из-за того, что не воспроизведена проблема и сама ошибка.

Comment: @DenisBubnov, не исключено, нужна реакция автора

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Метод ThenBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.enumerable.thenby(v=vs.110).aspx) нужен для того, чтобы можно было упорядочить значения в случае, когда поля в предыдущем сравнении имеют одинаковое значение, например есть последовательность

```
    a b
  -----
1 | 1 1
2 | 2 5
3 | 2 3
4 | 3 3
```

Применив к ней [OrderBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) по полю `a`, не гарантируется будут ли поменяны местами строки 2 и 3, то есть в итоговый результат может быть как

```
    a b
  -----
1 | 1 1
2 | 2 5
3 | 2 3
4 | 3 3
```

так и

```
    a b
  -----
1 | 1 1
2 | 2 3
3 | 2 5
4 | 3 3
```

В зависимости от сортировки, которая применяется внутри.

При использовании метода `ThenBy` по полю `b` можно конкретно задать, в каком порядке располагать объекты в случае, когда их поле `a` одинаковое.

Если вернуться к коду в вопросе, при такой группировке

```
toGroupList.GroupBy(n => n)
```

Поле `a`, в данном случае `Word`, будет уникальным, следовательно применяя `ThenBy` или нет, ничего не поменяется.